# FIFO multiplying console windows

Tags: c, pipe, fifo

Im trying to write a simple program:

Parent process forks twice:
(child#1):
reads bytes from /dev/urandom, converts them to hex and writes to child#2

(child#2):
reads from child#1 and printsf output to screen

The problem is when i run my program the first forking happens "too many" times...

file1.c (PARENT)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>


int pipe_table[2];
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char bufforek[256];
    int file;



        printf("LOL...\n");
        int pom=pipe(pipe_table);
        FILE *file2 = fopen("/dev/urandom", "rb");

        file=open("FIFO",O_RDWR);
        mkfifo("FIFO",0666);


        if(fork()==0)
        {
            execlp("/usr/bin/konsole", "konsole", "-e", "./file2", NULL);
            return 0;
        }
        //while (fgets(bufforek, sizeof(bufforek), file2)) write(file, bufforek, sizeof(bufforek));

        if(fork()==0)
        {
            dup(pipe_table[0]);
            execlp("/usr/bin/konsole", "konsole", "-e", "./file3", NULL);
        }
        wait(NULL);
        while (fgets(bufforek, sizeof(bufforek), file2)) write(file, bufforek, sizeof(bufforek));


        close(file);
        unlink("FIFO");


    return 0;
}
```

Child#1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
//#include "./file.c"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char bufforek[256];
  int tunel;
  tunel=open("FIFO",O_RDWR);
  int i=1;
  char pom;
  int pipe_table[2];
  mkfifo("FIFO",0666);
  int hexa;

  while(read(tunel,bufforek,sizeof(bufforek)))
  {
    pom = *bufforek;
    // printf("%hhX ", pom);
    write(pipe_table[1],bufforek,sizeof(bufforek));
    hexa = (int)pom;
    printf("%X ", hexa);
    if (i==15)
     {
       printf("\n");
       i=1;
     }
    else i++;

  }

printf("\n\n\n\nYOLO\n");
sleep(20);
  return 0;
}
```

Child#2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include "file.c"


int main2(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char pom;


      int bufforek[256];

       int i=1;


        while(read(pipe_table[0],bufforek,sizeof(bufforek)))
        {
      pom = *bufforek;
      printf("%hhX ", pom);
            sleep(3);
      if(i==15)
      {
        printf("\n");
        i=1;
      }
      else i++;
        }


    //close(pipe_table[0]);
    //close(pipe_table[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Why Child#2 doesn't launch at all? Can anyone help?

I think the problem is in line:

```
while (fgets(bufforek, sizeof(bufforek), file2)) write(file, bufforek, sizeof(bufforek));
```

Comment: It's "console" with a 'c'. Please format your code correctly.

Comment: emm... it is "Konsole" bud ;)

Comment: Not in English. You can print a string into a log-file to see if you are reaching child#2. I think you should take off the '2' from main2 for starter.